# Restrict Bootstrap navar to fixed height while allowing for custom icons in navbar menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place custom icons in a [Bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) while keeping the navbar at exactly 50px height. Even if I declare `.navbar { height: 50px; }`, after placing the icon, the navbar height increases a couple of pixels in height. Click on the link in the navbar and note the approx 2px space between the navbar and the dropdown menu (the navbar is 52px in this example due to the height of the icon).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hj3h58gm/4/

I understand the current behavior, I just don't know a way around it without decreasing the height of the icon, which I don't want to do.

Any suggestions?

The icon is denoted with `.el-ico`.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <nav class="el-nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              click this
              <span class="el-ico"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.el-nav {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.el-ico {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: url(icon.png);
}
```

Comment: try adding !important to the height of the nav bar

Comment: i've tried that, for both `height` and `max-height` but it's not obeyed.

Comment: I'd go against using background image for it. Bootstrap has a logo boilerplate already right?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the right selector with your CSS and use a media query with your `navbar` when adjusting for height because at under 768px you'll have adverse effects (your mobile dropdowns background will seem invisible when really the `navbar` is set at 50px, default is min-height: 50px).

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.el-nav {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
.navbar .el-ico {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default el-nav navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="el-ico"></span>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. The icons won't be displayed at < 768px though, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: It's has nothing to do with the icon, its the height of the navbar being set.

Comment: It actually does. To illustrate, I've reduced the icon height to 14px, now the navbar is at exactly 50px height: http://jsfiddle.net/hj3h58gm/5/ What I think I need is a way for the icon to not occupy space. I tried using absolute positioning to get that done, but then the dropdown menu doesn't get positioned properly.

Comment: You stated in your question you DO NOT want to reduce the size of the icon, hence why you wanted to fix the height of the navbar. If you dont need to alter the height of the navbar then it won't be an issue and if thats the only element in the navbar anyways.